# How to get correct decoding aspx url in file_get_contents?

Tags: php, html, unicode

I'm trying to get aspx url content b file_get_contents, But when I do this, the information returns inaccurately.

[image: Click to show image]

Html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=65004959184388996&c=27+";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You screenshot look like compressed response. To get plain text, try using this:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=65004959184388996&c=27+";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $data;
?>
```

You can also use below solution but this doesn't work on all servers.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0, compress;q=0\r\n",
    )
));
$url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=65004959184388996&c=27+";
$data  = file_get_contents($url, false, $contenxt);
echo $data;
```

I'll suggest to use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php) code because that **does support on all servers.**

Comment: @Farshid Cheers ^_^